# Sum values of specific columns using awk

Tags: bash, awk

So I have a file which looks like this:

```
1 4 6 
2 5
3
```

I want to sum only specific columns, let's say the first and third.
And the output should look like this:

```
7
2
3
```

I store numbers of columns (arguments) in a variable:
**`x=${@:2}`** (because I omit first passed argument which is a **`$filename`**)

How to calclute this using awk in a bash script ?
I was thinking about sth like this

```
for i in ${@:2}
do
    awk  -v c=$i '{sum+=$c;print sum}' $fname

done
```

But it does not work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$ awk -v c="1 3" 'BEGIN{split(c,a)}{c=0;for(i in a) c+=$a[i]; print c}' file
7
2
3
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v c="1 3" '  # the desired column list space-separated
BEGIN {
    split(c,a)      # if not space-separated, change it here
}
{
    c=0;            # reusing col var as count var. recycle or die!
    for(i in a)     # after split desired cols are in a arr, ie. a[1]=1, a[2]=3
        c+=$a[i];   # sum em up
    print c         # print it
}' file
```

**EDIT**: changed comma-separation to space-separation.

Comment: But what if I want larger number of arguments which are in variable x=${@:2}. For instance for larger file and this variable x is 1 2 3 4 5 6 ?

Comment: `awk -v c=$x ...` if `x="1 2 3 4 5 6"`.

Comment: Thank you i was fighting with using awk in for loop but your solution is better :)

Comment: I know. This place taught me to use Bash less and move more functionality towards Awk (and other tools).

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $1 + $3}' file
7
2
3
```